# How to implement a type system like typed racket using macros?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to implement a type system in racket.But i get in trouble when i write macros.it is diffcult to make my system compatible with original racket syntax.can anyone give me an example like Simple Typed Calculus in racket?
it seems impossible to write in this way:

```
(provide (rename-out [module-begin #%module-begin]
[app #%app] ...)
 ...)
(define-syntax module-begin ...)
(define-syntax app ...)
```

Comment: This question is much too broad for Stack Overflow. However, you may be highly interested in a recent paper, [Type Systems as Macros](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/stchang/popl2017/), as well as the accompanying library, [Turnstile](http://docs.racket-lang.org/turnstile/index.html). These provide tools for building typed languages in Racket without very much effort. For an example of implementing the simply typed lambda calculus using Turnstile, take a look at the [34 line example](https://bitbucket.org/stchang/macrotypes/src/f9199f6e3710018c2162f0453ae10ef164534063/turnstile/examples/stlc.rkt)!

Comment: @misaka Don't miss this blog post by Alexis: https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2015/12/21/adts-in-typed-racket-with-macros/

Comment: Thanks. I am going to study the paper.